# How to display hidden files in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

The icon for displaying all files in the solution is missing in the Mac version. How do I show hidden files on Visual Studio for Mac Community?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Right-click on the solution
2. Go to **Display Options**
3. Select **Show All Files**

---

[image]